# Is Roland Barthes' s/z structuralist or post-structuralist?

Tags: theory, roland-barthes

In [*S/Z*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/Z) (1970) the French literary theorist Roland Barthes analysed Balzac's story [Sarassine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarrasine). Is his method of analysis structuralist or post-structuralist?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/Z) says "Barthes's study has had a major impact on literary criticism and is historically located at the crossroads of structuralism and post-structuralism." Which suggests that the question of "is it structuralist or post-structuralist?" may be pretty hard to answer objectively.

Comment: If you need to write about this kind of topic, I assume you also have access to a library with books on literary theory. Part of being a student is also learning how to do research on your own. Learn to use library catalogues, learn to move from general works to more specialised ones, etc.

Comment: @Randal'Thor seems to me that very point makes this an interesting question.  I'd be highly interested in well supported answers unpacking the question and offering some conclusions.

Comment: @DukeZhou Yes, me too, which creates a dilemma: should I VTC [in the student's interest](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/10778814), or vote to leave open for my own interest?

Comment: @Chappo Any good answers on this subject would likely be instructive, and in the student's interest.  Also good for the Stack I would think if it garners some.

Comment: @Chappo I don't know what you mean by VTCing in the student's interest, but the Stack Overflow post you linked to isn't relevant here: please see instead [Literature's policy on homework questions](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/561/17).

Comment: @Randal'Thor That's a somewhat testy comment. Perhaps you should read my link more carefully - after all, it's relevant enough for you to have cited it in your own post. See in particular the two principles posited by the SO post, which form the basis of the homework policies on several of the other sites you reference; let me know if I need to spell it out. Note also that while your post is excellent, it's still simply your personal response to a Meta question, it's **not** our site's *policy*. FWIW, I voted to leave this question open. Like DukeZhou, I look forward to a good answer. :-)

Comment: @Chappo Sorry if I came off as testy; I wrote that comment in a hurry. Although the answer on our meta happened to be written by me, **yes it does form our site's policy** thanks to the community consensus formed by voting on it. No need to spell out anything from the SO post (which I admit I didn't read properly just now, although I probably did before writing that meta) since SO's policy doesn't apply on Literature :-)

Comment: @Chappo This is the type of theory questions that we don't manage to answer within a month, which is too slow for student essays. I won't even start looking at the relevant literature before February. In the mean time, I reworded it a bit.